# How to retrieve firebase database properly?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve the data from firebase database. However, I cannot get my local variables assigned to the values of the database. I am using the following classes and methods.

```
class Episode {

var title: String?
var description: String?
var location: String?
var discount: String?
var star: Int?

init() {
    self.title = ""
    self.description = ""
    self.location = ""
    self.discount = ""
    self.star = 0
}
```

This is my method for pulling the data from the databse

```
func getValues() -> Episode {
    let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Restaurants").child("The Kafe")
    let descriptionRef = rootRef.child("Description")
    let discountRef = rootRef.child("Discount")
    let locationRef = rootRef.child("Location")
    let starRef = rootRef.child("Star")
    let episode = Episode()

    descriptionRef.observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        episode.description = snap.value as? String
    }
    discountRef.observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        episode.discount = snap.value as? String
    }
    locationRef.observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        episode.location = snap.value as? String
    }
    starRef.observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        episode.star = snap.value as? Int
        print(episode.description!)
    }
    return episode
}
```

When I print out the values of the returned episode, they are all empty. However, when I print the values within the closure itself (Eg. if I do print(episode.description) within the obserEventType closure, it works fine. But if I print it outside it is empty.

I think I am missing something fundamental about swift or firebase. I am new to iOS programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only inside the first observer you will have the value the return will always be nil, that is because only the return is trying to work in a sync way while firebase will always work in an async way

```
rootRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(snap) in
        let ep: Dictionary<String,AnyObject?> = [
            "title": snap.childSnapshotForPath("Title").value as? String,
            "description": snap.childSnapshotForPath("Description").value as? String,
            "location": snap.childSnapshotForPath("Location").value as? String,
            "discount": snap.childSnapshotForPath("Discount").value as? String,
            "star": (snap.childSnapshotForPath("Star").value as? NSNumber)?.integerValue,
        ]
        //Here you have your data in your object
        episode = Episode(key: snap.key, dictionary: ep)
    })

rootRef.observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    print(snap.childSnapshotForPath("Title").value as? String)
}

return episode!
```

Also if you want to get it from a function like that you should probably use observeSingleEventType.

You need to rethink flow of your code because you are expecting firebase to work synchronously when it is always asynchronous. The way you have your getValues function will never work.

To solve this issue you should read about async execution and callbacks in swift.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I am very new to swift so I am still figuring out a lot of stuff. Can you briefly explain the difference between synchronously and asynchronously is?

Comment: Synchronous is that the code will be executed line by line, and asynchronous that different parts of codes execute at different times in different order and you cannot control the sequence of execution. actually swift works by definition in block codes that get executed randomly like the button events... as a programmer you don't know when the user will click the button but you need an event to handle what happens when the user click the button... is the same with firebase you don't know when firebase will give you the db information, but you still need to handle it

Comment: https://github.com/firebase here you can find some examples made by firebase about how it works with  iOS, maybe this will help you to get the idea...  and if you have doubts... you can always ask again here

Answer (score 3):

All Firebase events are asynchronous so they are executed in a non-sequential way, that is why you only have access to the data inside the context of the callback...if you put a print outside the callback it is executed in a synchronous way so it gets executed before the callback, that is why it is in its initial status

1) You only need the rootRef, delete the rest

```
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Restaurants").child("The Kafe")
```

2) You only need one observer

```
var episode:Episode? = nil

rootRef.observeEventType(.Value,withBlock: {(snap) in

   let ep:Dictionary<String,AnyObject?> = [
       "title":snap.childSnapshotForPath("title").value as? String,
       //Etc...
       "star":(snap.childSnapshotForPath("price").value as? NSNumber)?.integerValue,
    ]

    //Here you have your data in your object
    episode = Episode(key:snap.key,dictionary:ep)


}
```

3) your episode class can be like this

```
class Episode {

    private var _key:String!
    private var _title:String?
    //Etc.....
    private var _star:Int?

    var key:String!{
        return _key
    }
    var title:String?{
        return _title
    }
    //Etc....
    var star:Int?{
        return _star
    }

    init(key:String!, title:String?,//etc...., star:Int?){
        self._key = key
        self._title = title
        //Etc....
    }

    init(key:String,dictionary:Dictionary<String,AnyObject?>){

        _key = key

        if let title = dictionary["title"] as? String{
            self._title = title
        }
        //Etc...
        if let star = dictionary["star"] as? Int{
            self._star = star
        }
        ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! But for some reason I am still getting nil for the episode after calling "episode = Episode(key:snap.key,dictionary:ep)". Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: can you update your code to see what's your curren situation

Comment: I ran into the same problem again, where printing inside the closure would work but printing outside would give me nil